# mysqldump: not found - exporting database in python

Tags: python

I am trying to export a database using this code

```
os.system('mysqldump -u %s -p%s %s > %s' % (user, password, database, filepath))
```

When I run the program for the first time it exports my database and everything works fine just it gives me this error.

```
sh: 1: mysqldump: not found
```

Next run (when database is already exported) it works without any error.
how can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you mentioning like this  path/filename.sql  in file path?

Comment: filepath = '/home/sysop/Desktop/backup' + filename + '.tar'

Comment: I actually mentioned path/filename.tar because than I am going to compress

Answer (score 1):

You could locate mysqldump full path and use that.

In your terminal :

```
whereis mysqldump
```

You'll get its full path, which you can then use inside your python script.

Comment: Works fine thanks. I wrote locations manually as I see so will the program works for other computers as well ?

Comment: You could do whereis from within python.
Or maybe use that instead : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql_dump/0.2.2

Comment: Now it creates an empty tar file no database inside what could cause the problem?

Comment: Can you show your code ?
Also you can accept the answer pressing the "v" sign on the left

Comment: The main problem is that I want to make program work on any linux system without changing script